# smallrye.jwt.sign.key-location is Unknown property in application.properties

Tags: java, jwt, quarkus

I am currently trying to add JWT to my quarkus project but I have run into some roadblocks.
In my application.properties I have set the following settings:

```
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=publicKey.pem
smallrye.jwt.sign.key-location = privatetestKey.pem
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=https://example.com/issuer
```

but now I get the error:

```
Unknown property 'smallrye.jwt.sign.key-location'
```

I should have installed every necessary dependency in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-jwt</artifactId>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Or have I forgotten something?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration name was renamed to `smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location` (no dash between key and location), but I believe that the old one should still work because it was only deprecated.

Please try with the new name: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt#additional-smallrye-jwt-configuration